# get id from db and display contents in another page

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, permalinks

Basically I have a db with a table called apartments and I'm using this code to output the contents on one page:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_dice");
$query = "SELECT * FROM apartment ORDER BY ID DESC";
$records = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

//check connection
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
    echo 'err';
}   

while($show=mysqli_fetch_array($records)){
    echo '<div class="div-recentupdate" style="background-color:white">';
    echo '<a href="apartment.php">'.$show['apartment name'].' Bedroom:'.$show['bedroom'].' Price:$'.$show['price'].' <br></a>';
    echo '</div>';  
}
```

The question is simple (I'm used to mvc so that's why I don't know this, I'm sorry).

What I want is to output the contents of the db (apartment name, bedroom etc) on another page called the `apartment.php`

I think I'm supposed to use

```
<a href="apartment.php?id=(variable of the id of the chosen link)">
```

but I have no idea how.

Please help.

Comment: *"I think I'm supposed to use..."* - Yes, along with a `WHERE` clause. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html

Comment: yeah I know the question is basic but I don't know it (noob here) that's why I'm asking. You don't need to reiterate what I just said and how am I supposed to use a 'WHERE' clause in this situation if different id goes to different links. I was expecting a 'foreach' answer or something.

Comment: I've posted something for you below.

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw my answer or not, but had forgotten the connection variable in the query and made an edit for it; *sorry about that.* What I posted below works. If it's not working for you, then something is failing you and you need to check for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I think I'm supposed to use `<a href apartment.php?id= (variable of the id of the chosen link)>`"*

Correct, and make sure there are no spaces after the `=` sign.

First we need to use an `?id` in order to fetch the record from the database (and passed to the second page) while assigning it to the `id` row using:

- `$show['ID']` inside the `href` in your first page using your existing code that you posted.

Then on the second page, you would then use a `WHERE` clause using the fetched id from the variable and check if the assignment is set.

**Sidenote:** Your `ID` must be an `int` type in order for this to work properly.

In your first page:

Replace your current `href` line that's being echo'd with:

```
echo '<a href="?id='.$show['ID'].'">'.$show['apartment name'].' Bedroom:'.$show['bedroom'].' Price:$'.$show['price'].' <br></a>';
```

Then on your second page:

**Sidenote:** Using `(int)` for `(int)$_GET['id']` makes it a safe array.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){

$id = (int)$_GET['id'];

$query_fetch = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM apartment WHERE ID = $id");

 while($show = mysqli_fetch_array($query_fetch)){
    echo "ID: " . $show['ID'] . " " . $show['apartment name']. " Bedroom:".$show['bedroom']." Price:$".$show['price']." <br></a>";
 } // while loop brace

} // isset brace

else{
    echo "It is not set.";
}
```

**Another sidenote:**

You can also use the following instead of `(int)`:

```
$id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

---

**Footnotes:**

I noticed you have a space here `$show['apartment name']` between `apartment` and `name`.

Be careful with that, since spaces can cause problems if used in a query where you did not escape it using ticks.

I.e.: This would fail and cause a syntax error:

```
SELECT * FROM apartment WHERE ID = $id AND apartment name = 'apartment 101'
```

You would need to do and notice the ticks around the `apartment name` name:

```
SELECT * FROM apartment WHERE ID = $id AND `apartment name` = 'apartment 101'
```

It's best to use underscores as word seperators, *just saying*.

---

**Error checking:**

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connect))` to `mysqli_query()`.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Another thing I spotted, you are using the incorrect variable here:

```
$conn->connect_error)
```

it should be `$connect`, and not `$conn`.

Then your `echo"err";` will never happen, since you've used `die()`.

From the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

This language construct is equivalent to exit(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

> *"exit — Output a message and **terminate** the current script"*

Comment: alright, it worked thanks a lot :) and thanks for all the other sidenotes, footnotes and references you gave. I'll improve the code just like you suggested. Sorry for being a bit impatient before. Your effort sir, is highly appreciated.

Comment: @anyabythestars You're very much welcome, I was glad to have been of help, *cheers*